# How to write a pig algebraic udf for group by

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig, hdfs

i want to write a pig code to perform group by and generate sum of 31 fields, but before that i need to do some custom processing for which i wrote an eval function. i think i can make it run faster if i can include the GROUP and SUM operations into the UDF. To do this can i use algebraic UDF if yes how would my return schema of inital(), intermed() and final() look like, if no how else can i implement this. below is my code and thanks.

```
a = LOAD './a' using PigStorage('|') AS (val:int, grp1, grp2, amt1:long, amt2:long, amt3 ... amt31:long);

b = FOREACH a GENERATE myudfs.Custom(val) AS custom_val, grp1, grp2, amt1 ... amt31;

c = GROUP b BY (custom_val,grp1, grp2);

d = FOREACH c GENERATE group, SUM(b.amt1) ... SUM(b.amt31);

store d into './op';
```

Answer (score -1):

How is it possible to perform GROUP within a UDF...?

GROUP is being translated in Pig into a MapReduce job (intermediate key of this job will be combined from custom_val,grp1, grp2).

The ability to iterate (FOREACH) through the entire list of tuples for a certain group is being done in the the Reducer.

Algebraic UDF will not "include the GROUP", but will be executed as part of the GROUP aggregations. So I think that Algebraic is not relevant here.

I guess that the only optimization that you might do here, is to group on the original val, and to call myudfs.Custom(val) only after the GROUP.

**Assuming that your UDF is an [injective function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function)**.

```
a = LOAD './a' using PigStorage('|') AS (val:int, grp1, grp2, amt1:long, amt2:long, amt3 ... amt31:long);
c = GROUP b BY (val,grp1, grp2);
d = FOREACH c GENERATE myudfs.Custom(group) AS custom_val, SUM(b.amt1) ... SUM(b.amt31);
store d into './op';
```